# Create permutation of each letter in upper/lower from a given word

Tags: php, algorithm

I need to build a function - I don't know if this already exists on PHP - to create as many unique permutations of letters for a given word. Let's take this example:

```
#English
word: hello
output: HEllo, HEEllo, HEELlo, HEELLo, HELLO, Hello, HeLlo, HeLLo and so on 

#Spanish
word: hola
output: hola, Hola, HOla, HOLa, HOLA, hOla, hOLa, hOLA and so on
```

How I can achieve that? Can any provide me an algorithm to achieve this?

NOTE: keep in mind that words could be in english or spanish!

Comment: This is called permutation....I think I can help you out a little later. I created quite an algorithm for another user on here. I will link my answer for now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989174/php-order-multidimensional-array-in-every-possible-way-maintining-key-value-a/33992520#33992520

Comment: @VIDesignz pls, post an answer when you can, I have edited the post and change the wrong word, on the meantime I will check the post you leave me

Comment: Well, @rockacola got to it before me...bummer. Good for you though! Haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A potential approach as following (in pseudo code):

- assumption: input been English alphabet only, and in lower case.
- Work out the string length and create a `counter` integrate be 2 to the power of the string length. (Example: 'hello' been 5 characters and the `counter` be 32).
- loop through from 0 to `counter-1`, generate a binary representation of of this integer in the string length. (IE/ for word 'hello' is to loop from '00000' to '11111'.
- each iteration, map the word with the binary representation of current count, convert the character to uppercase when it has a '1' in its position. (Example: on 4th iteration 00011, result should be 'helLO')

Code:

```
function permutationWords($input) {
    $input = strtolower($input);
    $results = [];
    $length = strlen($input);
    $counter = pow(2, $length);

    for($i=0; $i<$counter; $i++) {
        $binaryStr = str_pad(decbin($i), $length, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

        $variant = '';
        for($j=0; $j<$length; $j++) {
            $variant .= ($binaryStr[$j] == '1') ? strtoupper($input[$j]) : $input[$j];
        }
        $results[] = $variant;
    }

    return $results;
}
```

[PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/iub2-dh7x)

There are definitely room for optimisation or even more efficient approach(es).

Comment: Did you notice my note at OP? Around words being in spanish and/or english?

Comment: is not working for spanish words :-\ can you take a look to this?

Comment: @ReynierPM, You can look into [mb_strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php) for non-ASCII support. Worse comes to worst you can also create your own dictionary on how the case conversion should looks like.

Comment: I am not following you on your latest comment around make word uppercase, what's the difference between `hola` and `HOLA`?